# Does Minas Tirith work with Doors of Durin?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Minas Tirith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=617086) lets you draw a card (as an activated ability, NOT a trigger) if you attacked with two or more creatures this turn:

> 1White, Tap: Draw a card. Activate only if **you attacked** with two or
> more creatures this turn.

[Doors of Durin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=617029) can put a creature into play attacking.

If Doors of Durin adds a second attacker, will that count for Minas Tirith, or does "attacked with" count only declared attackers?

To the close voters: **This is about a player, not a creature or its triggers.**

Comment: @PhilipKendall No. I'm just referring to that part because it's ambiguous whether Minas counts attack on declaration or later.

Comment: Which bit of the Kaalia ruling in the accepted answer to that question isn't clear? "Any abilities that trigger [...] when a creature attacks won’t trigger for that card."

Comment: Minas Tirith does not trigger when a creature attacks. Have you read the card?

Comment: While this question is similar to the proposed duplicate, the difference between "whenever X attacks" and "if you attacked with X" is enough to justify keeping this question open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.** According to the [Comprehensive Rules](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr508/):

> 508.6 A player is “attacking [a player]” if the first player controls a creature that is attacking the second player. **A player has “attacked**
> [a player]” if the first player declared one or more creatures as
> attackers attacking the second player.

So two creatures would be attacking for example a player (instead of a Planeswalker or Battle), but you only would have attacked with one creature.

[A separate question about triggers](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45811/with-regards-to-an-effect-that-triggers-when-a-creature-attacks-how-does-it-ent?noredirect=1&lq=1) is also explained here:

> 508.4 If a creature is put onto the battlefield attacking, its controller chooses which defending player or which planeswalker a
> defending player controls it’s attacking as it enters the battlefield
> (unless the effect that put it onto the battlefield specifies what
> it’s attacking). Similarly, if an effect states that a creature is
> attacking, its controller chooses which defending player or which
> planeswalker a defending player controls it’s attacking it becomes
> attacking (unless the effect has already specified). **Such creatures
> are “attacking” but, for the purposes of trigger events and effects,
> they never “attacked.**”

So "Whenever CARDNAME attacks" triggers don't, "[CARDNAME attacked](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=491623)" doesn't, and the full rule is: "**you attacked** with this instance of CARDNAME".

Comment: The issue is that declaring attackers and number of creatures attacking can be different numbers.  Anything that puts a creature into play attacking already doesn't count the creature at being declared an attacker

Comment: Rule 508.4 is the more relevant one here, as it directly addresses the question

Comment: @KMR Abilities cause effects, but the ability of Minas Tirith is about the player, not the creature.

Comment: Likewise [O-Kagachi, Vengeful Kami](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=578780) would not exile if you attacked its controller last turn without declaring it.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman you just need to read the last part _Such creatures are “attacking” but, for the purposes of trigger events and effects, they never “attacked.”_, otherwise you can also just look at the first ruling on __Windbrisk Heights__

Comment: @CeesTimmerman afaik, there is no way to attack a player without declaring. All “put onto battlefield attacking” trigger on attacks

Comment: @KMR Again, that's about creatures, and [the Windbrisk Heights ruling](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/details.aspx?multiverseid=145798) is about a player declaring attacks to have "attacked".

Comment: @MatthewJensen [Creatures entering attacking don't trigger attack effects.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45811/with-regards-to-an-effect-that-triggers-when-a-creature-attacks-how-does-it-ent?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [choosing attack targets does not declare.](https://www.reddit.com/r/mtgrules/comments/11bjxfy/comment/j9y5uu8/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I know. I mean there is no way to have an attacking creature without having declared some creature as an attacker. I was thinking there is no way to have a creature attacking O-Kagachi's controller without it triggering, but then I realised you can attack an opponent to have a creature enter attacking a different opponent.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Again, 508.4 is more relevant than 508.6, 508.6 is about one player attacking another, Minas Tirith will still activate if you attack a battle or planeswalker.
Both Windbrisk Heights and Minas Tirith have the same templated condition "if you attacked with {x} or more creatures this turn"

Comment: @KMR Noted, and that's completely different from "Whenever {x} attacks". Neither 508.4 or 508.6 are even mentioned in the answers to [the question about attack triggers.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45811/with-regards-to-an-effect-that-triggers-when-a-creature-attacks-how-does-it-ent?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

[Minas Tirith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Minas%20Tirith) **will not** count creatures put onto the battlefield by [Doors of Durin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doors%20of%20Durin).

Clearing up the Activation instructions on Minas Tirith may help here,

> Activate only if you attacked with two or more creatures this turn

is divided like this:

> Activate only if [player] [attacked with {x} creatures this turn]

The "*attacked with {x} or more creatures*" condition on **Minas Tirith** will only count creatures that have been declared as part of the *Declare Attackers Step*.

This is directly clarified by a ruling on [Windbrisk Heights](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Windbrisk%20Heights) that reads

> At the time the ability resolves, you'll get to play the card if you declared three different creatures as attackers at any point in the turn. A creature declared as an attacker in two different attack phases counts only once. A creature that entered the battlefield attacking (such as a token created by [Militia's Pride](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Militia%27s%20Pride)) doesn't count because you never attacked with it.

Which references the last part of rule **508.4** in the [Comprehensive Rules](https://magic.wizards.com/en/rules)

> 508.4. If a creature is put onto the battlefield attacking, its controller chooses which defending player, planeswalker a defending player controls, or battle a defending player protects it’s attacking as it enters the battlefield (unless the effect that put it onto the battlefield specifies what it’s attacking). Similarly, if an effect states that a creature is attacking, its controller chooses which defending player, planeswalker a defending player controls, or battle a defending player protects it’s attacking (unless the effect has already specified). **Such creatures are “attacking” but, for the purposes of trigger events and effects, they never “attacked.”**

Combined together; you (the active player) have only "*attacked with {x} or more creatures*" if you have declared {x} or more *different* creatures as attackers as part of the *Declare Attackers Step*.

Comment: Assuming we are correct about the part of my answer that explains that's about its controller, not itself.

Comment: ahh, you need to take the whole "something" to work out when a controller has done that "something", on Minas Tirith the "something" is not just "attacked"

Comment: Two creatures must have attacked, which means per 508.6 that the player declared them attackers. I could take control of creatures who attacked this turn but it's about me having declared them.

Comment: It's about the player (you) taking an action (attacking with two or more creatures this turn), 508.6 is not sufficient here, as you can still activate the ability after attacking a Planeswalker or Battle.

508.6 covers rules text on cards like [Curse of Verbosity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=433250)